# Check if XML node value already exists in xml file using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Please note that I'm new to C# and I learn it right now :) I couldn't find something similar to my problem, so I came here.

I have an application in which I add customers (it's in the final stage). All customers are stored in an XML file. Every single customer gets a new customer number. In my xml file I got an `XmlNode` called `CustNo`. Now if the user add a new customer and type in a number which already exist, it should pop up a message box to say that this number already exists. I got this c# code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path + "\\save.xml");
var xmlNodeExist = String.Format("Buchhaltung/Customers/CustNo");
var CustNoExist = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xmlNodeExist);

if (CustNoExist != null)
{
   MessageBox.Show("asdf");
}
```

And my XML file looks like this:

```
<Buchhaltung>
    <Customers>
        <CustNo>12</CustNo>
        <Surname>Random</Surname>
        <Forename>Name</Forename>
        <Addr>Address</Addr>
        <Zip>12345</Zip>
        <Place>New York</Place>
        <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
        <Mail>example@test.com</Mail>
    </Customers>
    <Customers>
        <CustNo>13</CustNo>
        <Surname>Other</Surname>
        <Forename>Forename</Forename>
        <Addr>My Address</Addr>
        <Zip>67890</Zip>
        <Place>Manhattan</Place>
        <Phone>0987654321</Phone>
        <Mail>test@example.com</Mail>
    </Customers>
</Buchhaltung>
```

But then the message box **always** pops up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your XPath return all `CustNo` elements, no matter of it's content.

Try following:

```
var myNumber = 12;
var xmlNodeExist = String.Format("Buchhaltung/Customers/CustNo[. = {0}]", myNumber.ToString());
```

or using `First` and LINQ to XML:

```
var myNumber = 12;
var xmlNodeExist = "Buchhaltung/Customers/CustNo";
var CustNoExist = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xmlNodeExist).FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x == myNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this could work with a little fix. `myNumber` is now "12". So the application check if there is a customer number with the value 12, right? And what about the value "13"? Or "14" & more? How to check these?

Comment: I think I could use `.innerText`. Is this possible? If yes, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Just change `myNumber` variable value with the number user typed as new customer number.

Comment: You mean textbox value?

Comment: Yes. But convert it to `int` first using `int.Parse`

Comment: But if I restart the application, the textbox value is empty but the customers still stored in xml file. So it would check for nothing

Comment: I don't get you. You said you have to check if customer with given ID exists when user tries to add new one. Why are you trying to check something when there is no new customer data at all?

Comment: Omg I'm absolutely sorry. I completely missunderstood! Thank you very much. It's late, I have to go sleep! One last question. I get an error that I can't use "int" and "string" together. You told me to use int.Parse. I tried but I don't get the right solution.

Comment: `int myNumber = int.Parse(yourString);`

Comment: Thank you very much! And again sorry! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently testing for existance of any 'CustNo' element. See [this reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the XPath syntax.

Your XPath should say something like this:

`Buchhaltung//Customers[CustNo='12']`

which would say "*any customers element containing a 'CustNo' element with value = '12'*"

Combining that with your current code:

```
var custNoGivenByCustomer = "12";
var xmlNodeExistsXpath = String.Format("Buchhaltung//Customers[CustNo='{0}']", custNoGivenByCustomer );
var CustNoExist = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(xmlNodeExistsXpath);
```

Comment: This solution works if I got only "12" as node value, right? What if I got numbers up to 100? Then I have to check if these already exists, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML

```
var number = textBox1.Text;
var CustNoExist = xdoc.Descendants("CustNo").Any(x => (string)x == number);
if(CustNoExist)
{
  MessageBox.Show("asdf");
}
```

Comment: don't you do it in your button click or something??

Comment: I'm just giving you an example,you should make your validates.It's not my job

Comment: Yes if the user hit the "AddCustomer" button. But what if I restart the program. Then the textbox is empty

Comment: I'm sorry. I completely missunderstood!

Comment: then just add an if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you select the `CustNo` elements regardless of their value. This will filter it to the desired customer number:

```
int custNo = 12;
var xmlNodeExist = String.Format("Buchhaltung/Customers[CustNo={0}]", custNo);
```

It selects the `Customers` elements instead, but since you're just checking for existence, that's unimportant.

W3Schools has a good [tutorial/reference on XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).